# Overleaf Latex detailed texcount always times out

Tags: overleaf, texcount

I am a PhD student with a paid version of Overleaf. I've been trying to do a detail tex count of my thesis following Overleaf's advice on [Overleaf TexCount Guidance](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Is_there_a_way_to_run_a_word_count_that_doesn%27t_include_LaTeX_commands%3F). It is impossible to get a detailtexcount done in the compile time allocated and I have followed all advice on [Overleaf Timeout Guidance](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Why_do_I_keep_getting_the_compile_timeout_error_message%3F).

Does anyone have any advice? I need a chapter by chapter breakdown that includes footnotes and so forth.

It's disappointing that a premium subscription product like Overleaf does not allow sufficient compile/timeout time for the texcount they advise.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you contacted the Overleaf Helpdesk? I hear their TeX support staffers are very knowledgeable.

Comment: Hi Simon, I've already replied to your support request to ask you for some info about your project so we can have a closer look. As the advice we give here will probably be quite specific to your particular project, let's continue in private email please. And then I can post an update here if there turns out to be some generally applicable advice for others.